# Rails_admin has many through is deleting both :through modals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through, rails-admin

I have `campaign`, `campaign_commissions`, `applicant` and `applicant_commissions` modals.

`campaign_commissions` are all `commissions` available for a `campaign` and `applicant_commissions` are the `applicants` *instance* of those `commissions`.

When I delete an applicant, rails_admin also wants to delete both campaign_commissions and applicant_commissions. I **only wish** for `applicant_commissions` to be destroyed.

How can I specify this to happen?

My Models:
applicant.rb

```
class Applicant < ActiveRecord::Base

  enum hired:  [:pending, :declined, :awaiting_post, :accepted]
  attr_accessor :post_url


  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :campaign
  belongs_to :site

  has_many :applicant_commissions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :applicant_commissions
  has_many :campaign_commissions, through: :applicant_commissions


  scope :accepted, -> { where('hired == ?', 3) }
  scope :declined, -> { where('hired < ?', 1) }
  scope :pending, -> { where('hired < ?', 0) }
  scope :awaiting_post, -> { where('hired < ?', 2) }

  validates :campaign_id, :presence => true
  #validates :site_id, :presence => true
  validates :applicant_commissions, :presence => true

  validates :campaign_id, uniqueness: { scope: :site_id,
                                        message: "We already have an application from you" }
```

applicant_commission.rb

```
    class ApplicantCommission < ActiveRecord::Base
      include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper

      belongs_to :applicant
      belongs_to :campaign_commission

      has_many :invoice_parts
      #delegate :user, to: applicant
end
```

campaign_commission.rb

```
class CampaignCommission < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :campaign
  belongs_to :commission

  has_many :applicant_commissions
  has_many :applicants, through: :applicant_commissions

end
```

campaign.rb (not involved in the issue, but added for context)

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :default => "500x500>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

  belongs_to :programme
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :applicants



  has_many :campaign_commissions
  has_many :commissions, through: :campaign_commissions

  has_many :images, as: :imageable

  scope :front, -> { limit(4) }

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

applicant_commissions reaches through to the campaign commissions via this relationship.

```
has_many :campaign_commissions, through: :applicant_commissions
```

I would suggest this to sever the tie to solve the problem you presented.

```
has_many :campaign_commissions
```

And, I didn't see this in your sample model, but for answer completeness I'll include it here. If you don't include the destroy attribute, the dependent record (or association dependent) will not be deleted.

```
 has_many :applicant_commissions, :dependent => :destroy
```

I don't think you can have the has many through relationship both ways, as live during application run but suspend the relationship when you want to delete the parent record. But maybe someone will come along with an answer and a way to do that.